# Django make the passed data invisable from view source

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I pass some data and process in my django template file. It works just fine. However, when i right click and then select `"view page source"` on my internet browser, i can see all the values that i passed from my `view.py`. How to hide the values in the template file.

**Child.page**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My amazing blog{% endblock %}


{% block extra_js %}
    <script>
        var secret_data = new Array();
        function mybutton(){

        {% for data in Mysecret%}
            // Here, I wanna make the value of data invisable
            secret_data.push({{ data.0 }})
        {% endfor %}

        }


    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <input type="submit"  name="submitButton"  value="Submit"  onclick ="mybutton();"> </input>

{% endblock %}
```

**When i right click and select "view to source" on my internet browser, i can see all the values something like that:**

```
<script>
        var secret_data = new Array();

        function mybutton(){

           secret_data.push("Secret-1")
           secret_data.push("Secret-2")
        }

    </script>
```

I have tried this:

```
secret_data.push({% csrf_token %}{{ data.0 }})
```

The values cannot be seen in case of viewing source code of the page, but at the same time it messes up the data that i pass (cannot access data cause the data turns out a div). How can i make my `secret_data` list invisible  so that if someone tries to view source of my page, she would not be able to see the passed values ("Secret-1" and "Secret-2").

Comment: What is the goal of this js code, where the `secret_data` ends up? Seems like a weird use case..

Comment: You can obfuscate client-side code, but you can't hide it.

Comment: @Brandon, obfuscating client-side should also work for me. Can you provide more explanation or an example?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.jsobfuscate.com/index.php

Comment: @Brandon, but i have some embedded django code like {% for loop %} in my javascript function, when i try to obfuscate it does not work in this way, how to do it with some django codes.

Comment: Hmm. That does complicate things a bit. It's possible to obfuscate JavaScript on-the-fly using something like YUI Compressor, but keep in mind that even if your code is obfuscated, *anyone* can un-obfuscate your code with very little effort and about 10 minutes of searching how on Google. My suggestion would be to move this functionality server-side.